# Images are searched in the wrong path

Tags: content, paths

I am working on a Wordpress 4.2.2 website which has a LayerSlider implemented in the front page. The slider used to work but some modification was done and now the images are not found. The images are searched in the path `www.mysite.com/home/wp-content/.../image.png`. Now, that `/home/` should not be there, while the rest of the path is correct. The same problem arises when I try to access the media library: the uploaded images are not found because of the wrong path. I tried to echo `WP_CONTENT_URL` and `WP_CONTENT_PATH`, but these constants are not defined. How can I fix this problem?

I don't know if this is relevant, but SSL is activated on the server with a 301 redirect.

EDIT: editing the `guid` column in `wp_post` table and removing every occurrence of `home/` seems to fix the problem, however I would like to better understand what could be happened in order to avoid that in the future.

Comment: I would update the installation ASAP. Maybe there's a conflict that can be resolved this way. Not to mention there are tons of security issues just sitting in your blog right now.